# Suppress custom line numbers with vertical rules on a particular page

Tags: rules

I use the following snippet to create legal pleading paper -- lines 1 to 28 on the left with two vertical lines, and one vertical line on the right.

**Q**: How can I suppress these vertical lines and line numbers for just a particular page?  [E.g., `\newpage` . . \suppress-pleading-paper]

```
% BEGIN vertical lines and line numbers.
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\leftruleA}
\setlength{\leftruleA}{3.0\leftmargin-\marginparsep}
\newlength{\leftruleB}
\setlength{\leftruleB}{2.8\leftmargin-\marginparsep}
\newlength{\rightrule}
\setlength{\rightrule}{2.6\leftmargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep}
\AddToShipoutPicture{
  \AtPageLowerLeft  {
  \put(\LenToUnit{\leftruleA},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \put(\LenToUnit{\leftruleB},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \put(\LenToUnit{\rightrule},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \rput(1.6,13.74) {
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5mm}
    \begin{flushright}
    \begin{doublespace}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\\11\\12\\13\\14\\15\\16\\17\\18\\19\\20\\21\\22\\23\\24\\25\\26\\27\\28
    \end{doublespace}
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage} }}}
% END
```

---

**EDIT**:  At the request of @A Feldman in the comment below, the following is the entire template that produces legal pleading paper (California) -- it works well with TeXLive 2012:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{geometry}
  \newgeometry{top=.84in, bottom=.7in, left=1in, right=.5in}
  \setlength{\footskip}{15pt}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{parskip}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{quoting}
  \quotingsetup{leftmargin=1in, rightmargin=1in, vskip=-1.5mm}
    \makeatletter
      \g@addto@macro\quoting\singlespacing
      \g@addto@macro\quoting{\vspace{-2mm}}
      \makeatother
    \makeatletter
      \renewenvironment{quotation}
        {\list{}{\listparindent=0pt
        \itemindent    \listparindent
        \leftmargin=1in
        \rightmargin=1in
        \topsep=-1mm
        \parsep \z@ \@plus\p@}
        \item\relax}
        {\endlist}
    \makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{pbsi}
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}
  {\fontsize{14}{14.5}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\ptm}{
  \fontfamily{ptm} \selectfont
  \fontsize{14}{0}
  \selectfont}

\newcommand*{\bsi}{
  \bsifamily \selectfont
  \fontsize{16}{15}
  \selectfont}

\usepackage{setspace}
  \doublespacing

\raggedright

\usepackage{tabto}
  \TabPositions{0.5in,1.0in,1.5in,2.0in,2.5in,3.0in,3.5in,4.0in,4.5in,5.0in,5.5in,6.0in,6.5in,7.0in}

\newcounter{foo}
  \newcommand\num{%
    \refstepcounter{foo}%
      \thefoo.}

\newcounter{counter-ROMAN}
  \newcommand\RONUM{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-ROMAN}%
      \Roman{counter-ROMAN}.}

\newcounter{counter-roman}
  \newcommand\ronum{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-roman}%
      \roman{counter-roman}.}

\newcounter{counter-arabic}
  \newcommand\arabnum{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-arabic}%
      \arabic{counter-arabic}.}

\newcounter{counter-alpha}
  \newcommand\alphanum{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-alpha}%
      \alph{counter-alpha}.}

\newcounter{counter-ALPHA}
  \newcommand\ALPHA{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-ALPHA}%
      \Alph{counter-ALPHA}.}

\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
  \setlength\topsep{0pt}
  \setlength\parskip{0pt}
    \begin{center} }{
    \end{center} }

% BEGIN vertical lines and line numbers.
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\leftruleA}
\setlength{\leftruleA}{3.0\leftmargin-\marginparsep}
\newlength{\leftruleB}
\setlength{\leftruleB}{2.8\leftmargin-\marginparsep}
\newlength{\rightrule}
\setlength{\rightrule}{2.6\leftmargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep}
\AddToShipoutPicture{
  \AtPageLowerLeft  {
  \put(\LenToUnit{\leftruleA},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \put(\LenToUnit{\leftruleB},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \put(\LenToUnit{\rightrule},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \rput(1.6,13.74) {
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5mm}
    \begin{flushright}
    \begin{doublespace}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\\11\\12\\13\\14\\15\\16\\17\\18\\19\\20\\21\\22\\23\\24\\25\\26\\27\\28
    \end{doublespace}
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage} }}}
% END

% BEGIN footer
\newcommand{\settitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\mytitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Title Not Set!}
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \cfoot{\vspace{-1mm} \ptm{-\thepage-} }
    \rfoot{\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\ \mytitle }
% END

% \usepackage{draftwatermark}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I am interested in this, so I +1 it, but if you would post a complete MWE that would be appreciated.  Is a "snippet" something that is particular to a LaTeX or TeX system?

Comment: @AFeldman -- I have edited the question to include the template for legal pleading paper.  I am a programming hobbyist, so I frequently see the word "snippet" as referring to a section of code that is just a fragment of the whole (sometimes a snippet can stand on its own two feet, but more frequently it is just a portion of code that requires additional parts).

Comment: Super!  Thanks so much, both for the MWE and the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just clear the settings with `\ClearShipoutPictureBG` and then reset it after the page. To make it a bit more convenient I put the vertical lines and line numbers in a new macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{geometry}
  \newgeometry{top=.84in, bottom=.7in, left=1in, right=.5in}
  \setlength{\footskip}{15pt}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{parskip}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{quoting}
  \quotingsetup{leftmargin=1in, rightmargin=1in, vskip=-1.5mm}
    \makeatletter
      \g@addto@macro\quoting\singlespacing
      \g@addto@macro\quoting{\vspace{-2mm}}
      \makeatother
    \makeatletter
      \renewenvironment{quotation}
        {\list{}{\listparindent=0pt
        \itemindent    \listparindent
        \leftmargin=1in
        \rightmargin=1in
        \topsep=-1mm
        \parsep \z@ \@plus\p@}
        \item\relax}
        {\endlist}
    \makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{pbsi}
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}
  {\fontsize{14}{14.5}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\ptm}{
  \fontfamily{ptm} \selectfont
  \fontsize{14}{0}
  \selectfont}

\newcommand*{\bsi}{
  \bsifamily \selectfont
  \fontsize{16}{15}
  \selectfont}

\usepackage{setspace}
  \doublespacing

\raggedright

\usepackage{tabto}
  \TabPositions{0.5in,1.0in,1.5in,2.0in,2.5in,3.0in,3.5in,4.0in,4.5in,5.0in,5.5in,6.0in,6.5in,7.0in}

\newcounter{foo}
  \newcommand\num{%
    \refstepcounter{foo}%
      \thefoo.}

\newcounter{counter-ROMAN}
  \newcommand\RONUM{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-ROMAN}%
      \Roman{counter-ROMAN}.}

\newcounter{counter-roman}
  \newcommand\ronum{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-roman}%
      \roman{counter-roman}.}

\newcounter{counter-arabic}
  \newcommand\arabnum{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-arabic}%
      \arabic{counter-arabic}.}

\newcounter{counter-alpha}
  \newcommand\alphanum{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-alpha}%
      \alph{counter-alpha}.}

\newcounter{counter-ALPHA}
  \newcommand\ALPHA{%
    \refstepcounter{counter-ALPHA}%
      \Alph{counter-ALPHA}.}

\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
  \setlength\topsep{0pt}
  \setlength\parskip{0pt}
    \begin{center} }{
    \end{center} }

% BEGIN vertical lines and line numbers.
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\leftruleA}
\setlength{\leftruleA}{3.0\leftmargin-\marginparsep}
\newlength{\leftruleB}
\setlength{\leftruleB}{2.8\leftmargin-\marginparsep}
\newlength{\rightrule}
\setlength{\rightrule}{2.6\leftmargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep}
\newcommand{\addlinenumbers}{
  \AtPageLowerLeft  {
  \put(\LenToUnit{\leftruleA},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \put(\LenToUnit{\leftruleB},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \put(\LenToUnit{\rightrule},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}
  \rput(1.6,13.74) {
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5mm}
    \begin{flushright}
    \begin{doublespace}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\\11\\12\\13\\14\\15\\16\\17\\18\\19\\20\\21\\22\\23\\24\\25\\26\\27\\28
    \end{doublespace}
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage} }}}
\AddToShipoutPicture{\addlinenumbers}
% END

% BEGIN footer
\newcommand{\settitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\mytitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Title Not Set!}
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \cfoot{\vspace{-1mm} \ptm{-\thepage-} }
    \rfoot{\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\ \mytitle }
% END

% \usepackage{draftwatermark}

\begin{document}
Page with line numbers.

\newpage
\ClearShipoutPictureBG
Page without line numbers.

\newpage
\AddToShipoutPicture{\addlinenumbers}
Page with line numbers.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!  :)